E91-Protocole the type of Bell state use in this protocol
my question is, what is the type of the Bell state used in Ekert-91
link for Bell states in question

correlated or anti-correlated.
And if they can use both of them , how do Alice & Bob know which one has been used?


In the Ekert-91 quantum key distribution (QKD) protocol, Bell states are used to create shared entanglement between Alice and Bob. There are four Bell states, two of which are correlated, and two are anti-correlated.

Correlated Bell states:
$|Φ^{+}⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$
$|Φ^{-}⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle - |11\rangle)$

Anti-correlated Bell states
$|\Psi^{+}⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$
$|\Psi^{-}⟩ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$


In Ekert-91, the correlated Bell states are typically used. The entanglement property of these states ensures that measurements on entangled qubits by Alice and Bob will be correlated when measured in the same basis. For example, if they use the same basis to measure a $|Φ^{+}⟩$ state, both will get the same result (either both 0 or both 1).
The protocol does not require specific identification of which Bell state is used, but rather it leverages the correlations/anti-correlations to ensure security. The choice of measurement basis and analysis of correlations is what guarantees security against eavesdropping.
How do Alice & Bob know which one has been used?
Alice and Bob don't need to know precisely which Bell state was used in advance. In Ekert-91, both parties measure their respective qubits in randomly chosen bases (e.g., rectilinear or diagonal). After measurements, they publicly compare a subset of their results to check for expected correlations, verifying that they are measuring an entangled state. If there's any discrepancy (indicating potential eavesdropping), they discard the key.
Ultimately, whether the Bell state is correlated or anti-correlated isn't directly used to infer anything by Alice and Bob in Ekert-91; they rely on checking the statistics and correlations of their measurement outcomes to ensure entanglement and thus security.
